# Is there a way to send dataframes from server to client in R?

Tags: r, tikz

I have an R script which I program on my laptop. After I am done, I FTP the R script up to my university cluster and run my code there (in parallel if needed). Most of my functions return data frames that I'd like to plot using ggplot. This is perfectly fine however I'd like to use `tikzDevice` to create tikz (latex code) for my plot to have the same font and style as my thesis.

**The problem:**
I can't run tikzdevice on the university cluster because of the lack of LaTeX packages. I also can't install them due to no `sudo` access. Essentially, this route is a dead end for me.

**Solution:** 
I can run tikzDevice on my own laptop. Since I am working on my latex document(thesis) on my laptop, its a seamless `\include`.

The problem is that the data (as dataframes) exist on the university cluster. I COULD save dataframes as textfiles, download them onto my laptop, and `read.table` them but this is gonna kill my productivity.

Are there any pacakges, tools, software, anything that will let me "extract" my data from the university server?

A possible solution is https://gist.github.com/SachaEpskamp/5796467
but I have no idea how to use this.

Note: I also don't know which part of the SE network this could go on.

Comment: `system(sprintf("scp %s",filename))` ?

Comment: Should be able to export `save()` dataframes as .Rdta files and have any R installation read them. So if you can send to the cluster via ftp you should also be able to also read via ftp. I don't see a problem.

Comment: @BondedDust That's a solution, yes but I spend more time updating code -> uploading -> running function -> downloading results -> creating plots. 

I was wondering if there is a way to setup some sort of connection between my R and server's R. I have also emailed my IT person to see if he can somehow "open a port" so I can directly access it. The best solution would be if I can mount my server folder onto Windows

Comment: You don’t need `sudo` to install software in general, you just have to install it into a different prefix. It seems you’re really trying to solve the wrong problem here.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround solution to this.

To those who are looking to transfer data back and forth from server/client, you can send and receive objects by serializing it.

On the server, you use the `saveRDS` command, and on the client you have the `readRDS` command. To provide a URL to readRDS, you must use gzcon, so like the following:

```
con = gzcon(url("http://path.com/to/your/object/serialized"))
a = readRDS(file = con)
```

Obviously this depends on some protocol installed on the server (like http)